# How to change opaque and make it strongly?

Tags: android, transparent

I need that my icon have color on 30% strongly that background.
I want to change background color and color of icon must change too:

[image: pic]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M18.9074079,13.6"
    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

I am try:

```
android:alpha="1.3"
```

and

```
android:fillAlpha="1.3"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Alpha only accepts values between 0 and 1

Comment: @LucasDeMoraisCabrales, I think you are right. But: May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#androidalpha 
Is it mistake?

Comment: That's strange, I'm not sure what's the behavior of "1.2" for example, maybe it's still capped at 1? Anyways, let me try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since alpha values are commonly known to accept values between 0 and 1, I'd suggest that you set your background to a certain lower alpha, such as `0.7`, and set your icon's alpha to fully opaque (`1.0`).

Comment: okay, I am mark this answer like a right. But I think I'll do it differently)